# MongoDB / Morphia update operation for document with many fileds

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have an entity that contains lets say 20 different keys / local variable. In case i want to update the doc ,  i can use the `UpdateOperations` in order to perform a query , but i have to go filed by filed and set the new value from the new object.. if there any way to update the current doc in db with only the new fields

lets say:

```
   public class item {

        @Id
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private ObjectId id;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String itemID;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String itemTitle;
..
..


    }
```

So lets say i have an item stored, now i got a new DTO from GUI, with only SOME of the fields , the rest are null. I want to create a generic update operation that will take only the non nullable values from the DTO object and will update it in the existing doc in the DB.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think so!

I see two possible ways:

Alternative 1: You can use reflection to iterate for every field in your DTO and put the value into a copy of the document recovered from DB. At the end of the loop you can update the document.

Alternative 2: Update only the desired fields. Mongo can update only a subset of fields in an update operation: [Update Data with Java Driver](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/update/)

Answer (score 1):

There's [merge](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/master/morphia/src/main/java/org/mongodb/morphia/Datastore.java#L427-L434) which should do what you need: `Work as if you did an update with each field in the entity doing a $set`